# How to add a script to Discard build and keep it for Max build#5

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy, cicd

I have 100 jobs on Jenkins and it not configured via any declarative pipeline.
Instead of going to individual job and enable discard build strategy and add Max build to 6.
Is there a script I can include ( bash script) where in the discard build is enabled for all jobs?

I tried with this script to enable for each job but failed

```
// Jenkins job
def jobName = 'foo'
// Range of builds to delete
def rs = Fingerprint.RangeSet.fromString("0-3", false);
// Set to true to actually delete. Use false to test the script.
def reallyDelete = false;

// ----------------------------------
def job = Jenkins.instance.getItemByFullName(jobName);
println("Job: ${job.jobName}");

def builds = job.getBuilds(rs);
println("Found ${builds.size()} builds");
builds.each{ b-> 
  if (reallyDelete) {
    println("Deleting ${b}");
    b.delete();
  } else {
    println("Found match ${b}");
  }
}
```

Also I am using Jenkins 2.332.2
or if I enable the Builder Discard in Jenkins - Manage Jenkins - Confguration -Global Build Discarders (will I don't need to enable to each job then and it is taken care), Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Global build discard configurations will apply to all jobs unless they have job-level configs set.

If you want to enable build discard configs for each Job, you can use the following script. Modify the script to suit your specific needs.

```
def maxDaysToKeep = 30
def maxNumToKeep = 6

Jenkins.instance.getAllItems(Job.class).each { job ->
  println("Updating the job: " + job.getName())
  job.setBuildDiscarder(new hudson.tasks.LogRotator(maxDaysToKeep, maxNumToKeep))         
}
```

Comment: Appreciated ycr for the help and the details.